# Why my timer reset button works erroneuosly in timer app?

Tags: java, android

I am relatively new to android. I thought creating a simple app like a timer would be a great way to start.

I managed to create my simple timer app, but I ran into an issue.

I got my app to start and pause, but I can't figure out how to reset it back to "00:00:00". I tried the following on lines 56-59 in my Java code.

```
package com.awesomeapps.misael.timer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button startButton;
    private Button pauseButton;

    private TextView timerValue;

    private long startTime = 0L;

    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

            }
        });

        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);

            }
        });
    }
    public void onButtonTapReset(View v)
    {
        timerValue.setText("00:00:00");
    }

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };

}
```

When I press my reset button it does turn into "00:00:00" but when press my start button the timer resumes where it left off. Like for example if the timer is at "00:05:123" ill press reset and itll change to "00:00:00" but when I press start again it picks off where it left off or maybe even a little further like "00:08:456" it wont start over from zero when I press reset then start again.

Can someone help me figure out my reset button, please?

I've attached some files in which I think my error might be in including the Java code at the above.

Strings xml file.

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Timer</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="timerVal">00:00:00</string>
    <string name="pauseButtonLabel">Pause</string>
    <string name="startButtonLabel">Start</string>
</resources>
```

activity_main xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/timerVal" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:text="@string/startButtonLabel" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
        android:text="@string/pauseButtonLabel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonReset"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timerValue"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onButtonTapReset" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I know my question is long, but I like being detailed.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the cancel button,  the text of the view is temporarily set to 00:00:000 because is still being updated in the background by the second Thread running through this code :

```
entprivate Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
        timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

};
```

You should consider the possibility of hitting the cancel button in this piece of code and act accordingly.

A fast solution in order to check if this is the case is to change the startTime to the current time in the OnClick Listener for the cancel button.
Time then should be set near "00:00:000".
If this is the case, then it is easy to figure out  a way to get it  working perfectly.

Comment: Could you show me how I could go about doing this? I've tried doing what you said and other things, but i just got more confused :( could you help me out? Thanks! :)

Comment: for start, change the cancel button listener to :     public void onButtonTapReset(View v)
    {    timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        timerValue.setText("00:00:00");
    }

Comment: and see if there is any result

Comment: Hey Nikos, I tried what you said but it does the same thing rest to 00:00:00 but then when I push start it resumes where it left off. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try changing your method to  public void onButtonTapReset(View v) { timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;  customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0); }

Comment: it didn't work, when I press the reset button then start it actually skips time lol any more help ?